# Wildcard redirects with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to match URLs at a specific path and redirect them to a subdomain (don't ask why I'm doing this in Javascript).

Basically I can do this for the basics, this is on a page at example.com:

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/weddings" || window.location.pathname == "/weddings/"){
    window.location.replace("https://blog.example.com/weddings/");
}
```

But now I need to do something similar for wildcards. I need to match `/weddings/*` and redirect to `https://blog.example.com/weddings/*`.

How do I do this with Javascript?

**UPDATE**

This seems to work, but is this the best method?

```
if (window.location.pathname.startsWith("/weddings/")) {
    window.location.replace("https://blog.example.com" + window.location.pathname);
}
```

Comment: can you try  the  **str.includes( "/weddings")**

Comment: @mariappank see my update above, I think `startsWith` is better, so it doesn't match somewhere else in the URL. I'm curious if this is the best method in JS. Better than some regex matching?

Comment: yes you can use **starstWith** this is  one of  best method in Javascript. if you have any doubts please check the javascript tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sample code.

```
const urlRegex = '/weddings/*';
if (window.location.pathname.match(urlRegex) !== null){
    window.location.replace("https://blog.example.com/weddings/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.prototype.match with regex

```js
const regex = /\/weddings\/(.*)/

const pathnames = [
  "/wedding",
  "/weddings",
  "/weddings/",
  "/weddings/a",
  "/weddings/b",
  "/weddings/c/d?e=f",
]

pathnames.forEach((pathname) => {
  const match = pathname.match(regex)

  if (match) {
    console.log(`https://blog.example.com/weddings/${match[1]}`)
  }
})
```

---

**Reference**

[String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this with [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)

The properties are are the same as `window.location` so you can check what's in the `pathname` and change the `host` accordingly. Then redirect to the resultant

---

Simplified example looping over a couple of test cases for demo purposes:

For live version just use `new URL(location.href)`

```js
const samples = [
  'http://example.com/food/',
  'http://example.com/weddings/',
  'http://example.com/weddings/nice-one',
  'http://example.com/weddings/foo?param=1'
]

samples.forEach(str => {
  const url = new URL(str);
  if (url.pathname.startsWith('/weddings')) {
    url.host = 'blog.' + url.host;    
  }
  console.log(url.href)
})
```